# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0 in android studio

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to run my emulator after adding the firebase and google sign in plug ins/dependencies to my gradle.build files and now I am receiving the error
"Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0"
anyone know if I am doing something wrong this is a react native firebase app.

I am not sure what to try. This is my first app I am doing for a project at school and I do not really know what I am doing. I have just been following tutorials online

Answer (score 1):

Solve this issue by deleting the `.gradle` folder from `<NameOfProject>/android` and again run `npm run android`

Comment: I approve this message!

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had this same problem. I don't have any idea what your error logs are though so I am not certain however this is my error log right here:

```
`> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
```

'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm targeta version. 1 actionable task: 1 executed`

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

`What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'. Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRun Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilat`

This error however I fixed by editing the gradle-wrapper.properties file's distributionUrl variable. I changed the distributionUrls gradle version to 7.4.2 the file is in   `Project-Name\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

My error log is saying that gradle's version of JVM want's to be version 11 and is not but you can check gradle's jvm version by using `cd android` in the project root directory and after that run `./gradlew --version` Change JVM's version from the version it is showing to the version that it says is required like in my case v 11. The way I changed gradle's JVM version required chocolatey which is a package manager. This is where you can require it https://chocolatey.org/install and after you have setup chocolatey open a new terminal that has administrative privileges and run this `choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11` with the JVM version it is asking for inside your error logs

and finally run `npm start` and after that `npm run android` inside a refreshed and new terminal and gradle's JVM version and gradle's version will be updated to the specified versions

Answer (score 0):

We could better help if you could you show us your `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle` files, but here are more specific instructions than you find in the docs:

In `android/build.gradle`, dependencies should look something like this:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:<version>")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:<version>")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

see: https://github.com/gyani-sunkara/rn-firebase-login-starter/blob/main/android/build.gradle

It is known this works with the classpaths at the beginning.

--

Also in `android/app/build.gradle`, it is known that the `google-services` dep works at the end of the file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and make this the last "implementation" under dependencies (around line 272)

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' // <-- add this; newer versions should work too
```

see: https://github.com/gyani-sunkara/rn-firebase-login-starter/blob/main/android/app/build.gradle

Then, delete `android/.gradle` and run `npx react-native run-android` in the root directory.

Comment: It's awesome that you are getting into mobile development for a school project! Sometimes, the react and react-native ecosystems come with a lot of decision fatigue. It's an important thing when you are learning to code to get stuff done quickly. You don't want to end up quitting due to an error that no one can explain to you. [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) and PWAs have exceptional and officially supported firebase documentation that helps you get stuff done quickly, and without errors that hole you up for a month. Coming from a middle schooler, this is a lot harder than some other frameworks